# Change the default text when writting emails in SharePoint designer to Arial

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

The default text when writing emails in SharePoint designer is Segoe UI size 3. I'd like to change this so each time I or anyone else opens Designer it's Arial. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no method to change the default font format in SharePoint email workflow.

You have to change it manually each time.